# Cancel All Operations + AFNetworking 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, afnetworking-3

I have created a class HTTPServiceProvider inherited from AFURLSessionManager. Added below code to get the data.

```
let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
let manager = AFURLSessionManager(sessionConfiguration: configuration)
let dataTask = manager.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (response, responseObject, error) in
         //Perform some task
}
dataTask.resume()
```

I want to add dataTask to operationQueue provided by AFURLSesstionManger and cancel all the operation in some other class (BaseController.swift) before calling the same request again.

**Tried this code but not working** -

```
self.operationQueue.addOperationWithBlock{
     //Added above code
}
```

And inside BaseController.swift file , called -

```
HTTPServiceProvide.sharedInstance.operationQueue.cancelAllOperations
```

But its not working :(

Thanks.

Comment: try this in every call before `manager.operationQueue.cancelAllOperations()`

Comment: Its not working because without adding any operation to the queue, how you can cancel the operation.

Comment: It may not be possible in this project but it is recommended to use Alamofire instead of AFNetworking when using Swift.

Answer (score 6):

For me best way to cancel all request is:

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager]; //manager should be instance which you are using across application
[manager.session invalidateAndCancel];
```

this approach has one big advantage: all your requests that are executing will call failure block. I mean this one for example:

```
        [manager GET:url
        parameters:nil
          progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull downloadProgress) {
              code
          } success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
              code
          } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
              //this section will be executed
          }];
```

2 things you need to know:

- it will cancel request performed only with this exact instance of AFHTTPSessionManager you will use for invalidateAndCancel
- after cancel all requests you have to init new instance of AFHTTPSessionManager - when you tried to make request with old one you will get exception

Comment: I want to add dataTask inside `operationQueue` and then cancel all operations inside `operationQueue`

Answer (score 3):

To cancel all dataTasks with NSURLSession:

```
manager.session.getTasksWithCompletionHandler { (dataTasks, uploadTasks, downloadTasks) in
    dataTasks.forEach { $0.cancel() }
}
```

Comment: I want to add dataTask inside `operationQueue` and then cancel all operations inside `operationQueue`

Answer (score 1):

I created an array of tasks:

```
var tasks = [URLSessionDataTask]()
```

then appended the `dataTask` which all I want to cancel before making new http request:

```
tasks.append(dataTask)
```

And to cancel all the operations, I used:

```
func cancelPreviousRequest() {
    for task in tasks
       (task as URLSessionTask).cancel()
    }
    tasks.removeAll()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use `AFURLSessionManager`

`// Invalidates the managed session, optionally canceling pending tasks.
- (void)invalidateSessionCancelingTasks:(BOOL)cancelPendingTasks`

Isn’t that what you wanted?